# In MVP design pattern, what is the purpose to use softReference for View in Presenter?

Tags: java, android, reference

When I use MVP design pattern in Android, some people suggested to use `SoftReference` for View in BasePresenter. What is exactly the purpose for this way?

I heard that it can avoid OOM occurred, but why? If I use StrongReference for View, I set the View be null when the Activity's `onDestroy()` method executed, it's not the same?

As I know, as lang as the Activity is to be destroyed, the `onDestroy()` method will executed. Isn't that?

1.Use SoftReference:

```java
    public abstract class BasePresenter<T>{

       private SoftReference<T> mSoftView;

       public void attachView(T view) {
           mSoftView = new SoftReference<>(view);
       }

       public void detachView() {
           if (mSoftView != null){
               mSoftView.clear();
               mSoftView = null;
           }
       }

       protected T getView(){
           return mSoftView.get();
       }
}
```

2.Use StrongReference:

```java
    public abstract class BasePresenter<T>{

       private T mView;

       public void attachView(T view) {
          mView = view;
       }

       public void detachView() {
          mView = null;
       }

       protected T getView(){
          return mView;
       }
    }
```

Comment: It's more of a java when the activity gets recreated, the view reference in presenter should be garbage collected, now if you don't hold a soft reference, then leak might occur as presenter still holds old activity reference during activity recreation (due to configchanges/screen orientation), better to use MVP/MVVM with  Clean architecture

Comment: Regardless of config changes or screen orientation, the Activity's onDestroy() method will be executed. So the presenter's detachView() method will be executed that the view reference in presenter will be set null. Can leak still occur?

Comment: onDestroy is not guaranteed unless explicitly triggered so yeah leak can still occur, and keeping a view reference in presenter in not MVP proper.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's to say, the onDestroy method may not be invoked in some case. That' s the point I confused. I read some documents, they said activity destroyed by unusual way, the onDestroy method still can be invoked. Also, as you said in the last, the presenter shouldn't to keep a view reference, then how can I update the UI after my presenter's code executed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Through Interfaces, your view should implement an interface and that reference to passed to presenter constructor, now with that you send result back to view